# Expected one assertion to be called but received zero assertion calls. Why?

Tags: javascript, promise, jestjs

I'm writing a `rejectOnTimeout()` function that should return a rejected promise with a `timeout_error` value if the promise didn't complete in `ms`, or return a promise that reflects the behavior of the original promise.

The answer I get is correct, I think. But I don't understand the meaning of the error `Expected one assertion to be called but received zero assertion calls`.

What am I doing wrong in this case?

```js
const delay = require('delay');

/**
 * @param  {Promise} original promise 
 * @param  {Number}  ms for timeout
 * @return {Promise}
 */
const rejectOnTimeout = (promise, ms) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const start = Date.now();

  promise.finally(() => {
    const time = Date.now() - start;

    if (time <= ms) {
      resolve(promise);
    }
    reject('timeout_error');
  });
});

// Test 1 [PASSED]
rejectOnTimeout(Promise.resolve(10), 100)
  .then(data => console.log(data)) // 10
  .catch(err => console.error(err));

// Test 2 [PASSED]
rejectOnTimeout(Promise.reject(10), 100)
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(err => console.error(err)); // 10

// Test 3 [FAILED], REASON: Expected one assertion to be called but received zero assertion calls.
const delayed = delay(100, { value: 10 });

rejectOnTimeout(delayed, 50)
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(err => console.error(err)); // timeout_error
```

Test code:

```js
describe('rejectOnTimeout', () => {
    it('rejectOnTimeout, 01', async() => {
      expect.assertions(1);
      await expect(rejectOnTimeout(Promise.resolve(10), 100)).resolves.toBe(10);
    });

    it('rejectOnTimeout, 02', async() => {
      expect.assertions(1);
      await expect(rejectOnTimeout(Promise.reject(10), 100)).rejects.toBe(10);
    });

    it('rejectOnTimeout, 03', async() => {
      expect.assertions(1);
      const delayed = delay(100, { value: 10 });

      await expect(rejectOnTimeout(delayed, 50)).rejects.toBe('timeout_error');
    });

    it('rejectOnTimeout, 04', async() => {
      expect.assertions(1);
      const delayed = delay.reject(100, { value: 10 });

      await expect(rejectOnTimeout(delayed, 50)).rejects.toBe('timeout_error');
    });

    it('rejectOnTimeout, 05', async() => {
      expect.assertions(1);
      const delayed = delay(100, { value: 10 });

      await expect(rejectOnTimeout(delayed, 1000)).resolves.toBe(10);
    });

    it('rejectOnTimeout, 06', async() => {
      expect.assertions(1);
      const delayed = delay.reject(100, { value: 'error' });

      await expect(rejectOnTimeout(delayed, 1000)).rejects.toBe('error');
    });
```

Comment: Can we have the test code as well?

Comment: yep, I added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was getting a different error when I plugged your code into my editor:

```
● rejectOnTimeout › rejectOnTimeout, 03

thrown: 10
```

The problem was the previous test was throwing an unhandled rejection into the test environment and everything exploded. After changing the `rejectOnTimeout` implementation to this, all the tests passed:

```
const rejectOnTimeout = (promise, ms) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const start = Date.now();

    promise
      .catch((e) => reject(e))
      .finally(() => {
        const time = Date.now() - start;

        if (time <= ms) {
          resolve(promise);
        }
        reject("timeout_error");
      });
  });
```

`Promise.finally` does not actually handle rejections, it just triggers whether the Promise rejects or resolves. So while our new Promise inside `rejectOnTimeout` may complete correctly, the underlying promise argument is not being handled.

Catching internally seems to preserve the behaviour you are looking for. Presumably we don't actually care whether there was a timeout if the promise already threw an error. It doesn't matter what happens in `finally` either since you can't overwrite the result of a Promise after already rejecting it.

Here is how I would go about implementing this functionality:

```
const rejectOnTimeout = (promise, ms) => {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     setTimeout(() => reject("timeout_error"), ms);
     
     promise
       .catch((e) => reject(e))
       .finally(() => resolve(promise));
   });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but try this: rejectOnTimeout(delayed, 50) I get 10 instead timeout_error

Comment: const delayed = delay.reject(100, { value: 10 });

Comment: if we process first finally (), then catch (), there is no error, however, errors appear in other tests

Comment: I added other tests

Comment: Well, to be honest, I would consider that expected behaviour with the current implementation. Your function doesn't really behave like a timeout because it's waiting for the original promise to complete, but it shouldn't actually care what that promise does. It should reject *early* if the timeout expires. I think you need to go back and look at how you could separate the logic - an actual call somewhere to `setTimeout` would probably be a good place to start.

Comment: but how do we then know how long it takes for the original promise to complete? we have to call Date.time () before start and after execution to compare against the ms argument. How setTimeot () can help here, I don't understand ...

Comment: in general, using the debugger, you can see that it should reject the error, but for some reason it outputs 10.

Comment: specifically this: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: 10

Comment: See the edit. We don't need to know how long the original promise takes to resolve, we're just rejecting from our current promise early if it takes too long. I don't think it needs to do anything else. If you wait until the original promise resolves, you might end up hanging forever and *never* timing out which is the exact opposite of what this seems like it should solve.

Comment: I will add that maybe you don't want to catch other errors internally with `rejectOnTimeout`. I included the `catch` block because it makes your tests pass, but maybe it shouldn't do that. Maybe `rejectOnTimeout` should *only* reject on a timeout, in which case your test cases are incorrect because promises rejected inside the function could *not* accurately be described with `expect...rejects` wrapped around the outer layer. Let me know if this is the case and I might be able to suggest some better test cases.